# XML http response doesn't work

Tags: javascript, php, validation, xmlhttprequest

I have created a program for my website which onkeyup validates an username. It uses javascript with XMLHttpRequest. I don't know what's wrong with my code. The js code is:

```
    function search(username)
{
var xmlhttp, answer;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else if (window.ActiveXObject)
{
// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
else
{
alert("Sorry, your browser seems to not support XMLHTTP functionality.");
}


xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if(xmlhttp.readyState==4)
{
answer=xmlhttp.responseText;
if(compare_strings(answer,1))
{
document.getElementById("nameInfo").className="error";
document.getElementById("username").className="error";
document.getElementById("nameInfo").innerHTML="Please enter your desired username.";
}
else if(compare_strings(answer,2))
{
document.getElementById("nameInfo").className="error";
document.getElementById("username").className="error";
document.getElementById("nameInfo").innerHTML="The username <strong>"+username+"    </strong> is not allowed.";

}
else if(compare_strings(answer,3))
{
document.getElementById("nameInfo").className="error";
document.getElementById("username").className="error";
document.getElementById("nameInfo").innerHTML="The username <strong>"+username+"    </strong> has already been taken.";

}
else
{
document.getElementById("nameInfo").className="success";
document.getElementById("username").className="";
document.getElementById("nameInfo").innerHTML="Username <strong>"+username+"</strong>     is available.";
flag=1;

}
}
}
var url="ajax_search.php";
url=url+"?q="+username;
url=url+"&sid="+Math.random();
xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
xmlhttp.send(null);
/*It has been assumed here that ajax_search.php is in the same directory.*/
xmlhttp.send(null);
}
```

My php code works. When I load the website and put a q behind the .php? it echoes the right answer.
Here is the code anyway:

```
function chek_avail($username)
{
global $link;
$length=strlen($username);
if($length==0)
$res=1;
else if($length>5 && $length<15)
{
$res=4;
$query = "SELECT * FROM users";

if($result=$link->query($query)){
while($row=$result->fetch_assoc())
{
if(strcmp($username,$row['username'])==0)
$res=3;
}
}
}
else
$res=2;
echo $res;
}
$username=$_GET["q"];
chek_avail($username);
?>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I suggest that you use jquery to get rid of this javscript mess.

Comment: I wouldn't know how to, to be honest.

Comment: Do you see any errors in your console?

Comment: I can't find any errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, old school AJAX requests. They bring back such... nightmares.
Could I suggest jQuery instead? [Get](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) is such a handy function

```
jQuery().get('your URL here', function(answer) {
    if(compare_strings(answer,1))...
    // the rest of your code here
});
```

That's it! You don't need to write your own AJAX anymore. Works with all browsers and inconsistencies. Seriously, nobody does it the way you're doing it anymore.

Now, about your PHP... You're fetching the entire `users` table and then looping through it to find the username? How about letting your database do the work instead?

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = (?)";
$stat = $link->prepare($query);
$stat->bind_param("s", $username);
$stat->execute();
$result = $stat->get_result();
$stat->close();
```

You can keep the same code from there on out, but your database can now share the load and tell you if your `$username` is in there. And this code is SQL injection safe. Better still is you're not looping through your entire `users` table every time you do this.

Comment: I changed the php - it's better now, thanks. I have no idea how to do this with jquery though (what to replace, what to leave). I also do not know how to activate/install jquery.

Comment: I seriously can't recommend a framework enough. Writing your own AJAX is one of the few things I don't suggest anyone do. Installing jQuery is really easy incidentally http://jquery.com/download/